# tweepy old tweets

Tags: python, tweets, tweepy

Tweepy streaming api gives me live tweets being tweeted. So is there any way to fetch tweets from stock of tweets tweeted before script starts running. Like, last 100 tweets.

My requirement is to get last 100 tweets, with a keyword in them posted by anyone in the world using tweepy

Answer (score 1):

If you're not looking to get a massive amount of previous tweets, you can use:

```
ret = api.user_timeline(screen_name = 'Bob', count = 100, include_rts = True)
```

To get the last 100 tweets for the user `Bob`. Ret will be a list of `Status` objects.

Comment: This works for streaming for a particular user tweets, But how can we stream entire twitter for past tweets?